# include media queries in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.slider-home').slick({
 slidesToShow: 4,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 asNavFor: '.slider-for, .slider-arrow',
 focusOnSelect: true,
 autoplay: false,
 arrows: true
});
```

I am trying to add a media query so that the slidesToShow changes from 1 on mobile to 4 on desktop.

I have tried the following code:

```
if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 1024px)').matches) {
jQuery('.slider-home').slick({
slidesToShow: 1
});
} else {
jQuery('.slider-home').slick({
slidesToShow: 4
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work, does any body have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: why don't just use css to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `$(window).width()` if you really want to achieve it in javascript code. The code can be as follows:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth < 1024)
{
    jQuery('.slider-home').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1
    });
}
else {
    jQuery('.slider-home').slick({
       slidesToShow: 4
    });
}
```

But at the same time you will have think about screen rotation event too. Because in some devices it may possible that `portrait` screen size is less than `1024` and `landscape` have greater than this limit.